# двумерный массив как параметр функции

Tags: c

```
int main() {
   setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
   int mat[N][N], n, *p;
   printf_s("Введите размер матрицы: "); scanf_s("%d", &n);
   printf_s("Введите элементы матрицы: \n");
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
       for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
           scanf_s("%d", &mat[i][k]);

   if (is_ident(&mat[0][0], n)) printf_s("Матрица единичная");
   else printf_s("Матрица НЕ единичная");

   return 0;
}

int is_ident(int *mat, int n) {     

   int t = 0, *p;
   int B, C ;
   for (B = 0; B < n; B++) {
       for (C = 0; C < n; C++) {
//проверка для ячеек которые не по главной диагонали расположены(они должы быть нулями):
           if (B != C) {
               if (mat[C + n * B] == 0) { t++; }
               else { t = 0; break; }
           }
//проверка для ячеек которые расположены по главной диагонали(они должны быть единичками):
           if (B == C) {
               if (mat[C + n * B] == 1) { t++; }
               else { t = 0; break; }
           }

           C++;
           if (C == n) { B++; C = 0; }
       }
   }

   if (t == 0) return 0;
   else return 1;
}
```

Эта функция определяет - единичная матрица или не единичная. У меня проблема в условии проверки mat[C+n*B]== 0 и mat[C+n*B]== 1 . Мне сказали что так как я  передаю указатель массива только, то нужно "использовать одномерный индекс: a[j + n*i], где n - это количество столбцов в двумерном массиве". Как правильно записать условие цикла?
Мне сказали - это я прочитал ответ на этом ресурсе на подобный вопрос: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671046/Двухмерный-массив-как-параметр-функции-c/1275764#1275764](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671046/%D0%94%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-c/1275764#1275764)

Comment: Указывайте в метках язык программирования

Comment: `int is_ident(int ( * mat ) [N], int n) ` ... `mat[x][y]`

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали массив с размерностью **N**x**N** а вычисляете позицию элементов используя совсем другое число **n**. Проще всего массив нужного размера сделать.

```
scanf_s("%d", &n);
int mat[n][n];
```